# Double $rootScope in Angularjs app

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

This problem makes me a huge headache - I don't know why, but in my application i have two $rootScope, with $id "001" and "003" (each has separated variables). I checked ng-app occurrence and it's only once at main page.

Anyone have any idea why it is like that ?

Angular 1.1.5 (same on 1.0.7)

Index.cshtml

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Cassette.Views.Bundles.RenderStylesheets()
</head>


<body id="body" class="container-fluid"  ng-app="app">
    <div ng-view ng-cloak class="row-fluid">
    </div>
    @Cassette.Views.Bundles.RenderScripts()
</body>
</html>
```

App.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource', 'ngCookies'])
    .config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
        var access = RoutingConfig.accessLevels;

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
        $routeProvider
            .when('/',
                {
                    redirectTo: '/Entries'
                })
            .when('/Login',
                {
                    templateUrl: 'Views/Security/Login',
                    controller: 'LoginController',
                    access: access.anonymous
                })
            .when('/Entries',
                {
                    templateUrl: 'Views/Entry/List',
                    controller: 'EntryListController',
                    access: access.user
                });
    }])
    .run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'SecurityService', function ($rootScope, $location, SecurityService) {
        $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
            $rootScope.error = null;
            if (!SecurityService.Authorize(next.access ? next.access : RoutingConfig.accessLevels.public)) {
                if (SecurityService.IsLoggedIn()) {
                    $location.path('/');
                }
                else {
                    $location.path('/Login');
                }
            }
        });
    }]);
```

Just to make sure both templates are empty. $rootScope is changing on second $locationChangeStart :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't been able to reproduce your problem - but we've seen similar trouble with double controllers / scope because we accidentally specified the controller twice - once in the routing tables (`$routeProvider.when(..., controller="xyzCtrl", templateUrl="xyz.html"`) and again in my template (`data-ng-controller="xyzCtrl"`). Removing either one of them fixed the problem. Hope this is a clue in the right direction.

Comment: Shame on me - it was double angular.js on page :( Thanks for moving me on a right track.